# Google alerts - can't tell where my site is mentioned

Tags: google

I recently signed up for google alerts. I get emails whenever my site is mentioned anywhere on the web.

The problem is that I can't figure out where my site is mentioned from the emails they send me.

Here is how their emails look like:

```
Web 1 new result for comehike.com

Hiking Sticks and Poles - Come Hike
Hiking sticks and poles help you prevent injury to your joints and take the stress of the joints while hiking. They can also help you prop yourself and protect you ...
hiking.comehike.com/outdoors/hiking_sticks.php
```

But how do I tell who mentioned it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is bound to happen because the Googlebot scans sites and later Google Alert scans the indexed data and sends you an email.** There is therefore a window of time from the time the mention is detected to the time you get the alert and go check it out.

When it is still there, **the last link is the URL where the mention was found**. If you do not see it easily, search for it. On most browsers, CTRL-F will do. If you still do not see it, try the source-code CTRL-U than CTRL-F.

There may be numerous reasons why the mention is not there anymore:

- The mention was part of semi-random content (latest posts, popular item lists, etc).
- The mention has aged. This will happen the most for blogs where contents constantly move from the from page to the next.
- The mention was deleted.
- The site shows different contents to different users based on a variety of factors like language, location, cookies, screen size, user-agent, etc.
- The site may unintentionally mislead Google if they have errors in the URL.
- The site may be intentionally misleading Google (cloaking).